# DHCPv6 Server IP address

Tags: dhcp-server

I am new to DHCPv6. In dhcpv4 we have Option 54 to retrieve the Server Identifier (ie. Server IP address) in DHCP message. Similarly how to retrieve DHCPv6 Server IPv6 address in DHCPv6 Message. I know we have Server Identifier Option in DHCPv6 . but it gives only DUID(link layer address). We need to know Server IPv6 address in the DHCPv6 message . Pls suggest me..

Comment: it is urgent..pls give any other pointer to refer this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 3315, Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315#section-5.1), all DHCPv6 server listen for the same multicast addresses, namely `ff02::1:2` (link-scope, includes DHCPv6 relays) and `ff05::1:3` (site-scope, excludes DHCPv6 relays).

Depending on the situation, these pre-defined addresses may suffice as "IPv6 server address" and hence don't need to be listed as DHCPv6 option in the packet.